# How to crawl Googlemaps from VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, google-maps, web-crawler, extract

As a real beginner in coding, I am looking for some help around here !

I would like to extract data from GoogleMaps: let's say, Zip code, from a company input in a cell in excel, through VBA.

As I started coding, I met difficulties at the string level as I can't target the accurate tag (here, I think, but thats the point, span) and effectively extract the zip code on the address line on Googlemaps HTML page :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = Range("nom").Row And _
    Target.Column = Range("nom").Column Then
     Dim GM As New InternetExplorer
     GM.Visible = True
     GM.navigate "https://www.google.fr/maps/@43.3082377,5.4259519,17z?q=" & Range("nom").Value
     Do
     DoEvents
     Loop Until GM.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     Dim doc As HTMLDocument
     Set doc = GM.document
     Dim sSPAN As String
     sSPAN = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(4).innerText)
     MsgBox sSPAN

    End If
End Sub
```

Line 13 displays the following errors :

> Run Titre Error 91 : object variable or with block variable not set

as I can't select the accurate block.

Following this, I have two questions:

1. Is it effectively possible to extract data from Google Maps ? (Through VBA or an opensource Google API, extracting from Google sheet (10000-lines excel)
2. Has someone ever facde this kind of difficulty ? How can I select the accurate block on Googlemaps HTML page?

Comment: Here you will find an overview about the [Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation) that are available. I recommend to use an API which is much more reliable than web-crawling. The API might look more difficult in the beginning but the web-crawler would need to be fixed in future everytime Google changes their output on Maps.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how I would go about it and API is definitely preferable though not via GoogleMaps unless you are building an application where you can also embed the required map.

You need a proper page load wait, a wait for the element to be present, quit the application at the end, and use a different selector strategy. You also want to implement some logic to extract the post code from address (I am not sure what view you were getting. I used a test value of `Enterome`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim t As Date, gm As New InternetExplorer
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    If Target.Row = Range("nom").Row And Target.Column = Range("nom").Column Then

        gm.Visible = True
        gm.navigate "https://www.google.fr/maps/@43.3082377,5.4259519,17z?q=" & Range("nom").Value

        While gm.Busy Or gm.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim elem As Object

        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set elem = gm.document.querySelector(".section-info-text")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While elem Is Nothing

        If Not elem Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox Trim$(elem.innerText)
            'Implement logic to extract post code
        End If
        gm.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```